# How to assign route workflow function to a push button in IBM Maximo Asset Management application?

Tags: maximo

Pushbutton properties

[image]

I have created a button in the application designer and defined the properties as shown in the picture, but when i go to the respective application - the button is like read only state. not able to click.

Comment: Hi Arun, Welcome to SO.
Your question would be more pertinent for the site if you provided a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you show the current state of your code and tell us what you have tried already to make it work.

Comment: Do you have route workflow rights for that application. If that sigoption does not exists, you need to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not given the access for this sigoption in your Security Group. Please go to your Security Group and give access for the same and try again After logging out and back in